# Find last column

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Last_Column = 0
On Error Resume Next
Last_Column = Sheets("Combined").Cells.Find("", [a1],, , _
                           xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
```

When the sheet has no data it returns 
Run time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set,

How can I get it to continue, or what do I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[update: and you should be looking for `"*"` not '""'**

You are better off using a range object and then testing whether it exists, ie

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim Last_Column As Long
Set rng1 = Sheets("Combined").Cells.Find("*", [a1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    Last_Column = rng1.Column
Else
    MsgBox "No data", vbCritical
End If
```

Comment: I just saw your other response. You can continue with formatting either after the `Else` (different formatting depending on whether `Last_Column' exists) or `End If` above (ie same formatting for sheet with content or not). My query would be though what would you format in an empty sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check to make sure that the data sheet is not empty or null before running your code.  Then inform the user that the sheet is empty.

Comment: Hi, but when it's empty I still want to be able to with formating the sheet, eg. headings etc.